# How can a class's memory-allocated address be determined from within the constructor?

Tags: c++, class, instantiation

Is it possible to get the memory-allocated address of a newly-instantiated class from within that class's constructor?
I am developing a linked list where multiple classes have multiple pointers to like classes.  Each time a new class instantiates, it needs to check its parent's list to make sure it is included.

If I try to do something like this:

```
MyClass() // constructor
{
   extern MyClass * pParent;

   for ( int i = 0; i < max; i++ )
   {
      pParent->rels[i] == &MyClass; // error
   }
}
```

I get this error:

> error C2275: 'namespace::MyClass' : illegal use of this type as an expression

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused, it sounds like you want the `this` pointer . . .

Comment: dreamlax, just answer. my guess is, it's a correct answer.

Comment: @dreamlax, Thanks!  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Please add it as an answer, and I'll accept it.  Usually, I write embedded C for microcontrollers, so some of the special keywords specific to C++ are new to me.

Comment: I am still confused why you would want to do that. Why would the address of a newly allocated object already be known in another object *(except for some evil bug)*? Other instances only get it from `new` et al *after* the constructor has finished.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you mean to do:

```
pParents->rels[i] = this;
```

Comment: Comparison versus assignment doesn't really matter.  I'm using both.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that it's considered bad form to pass `this` around from a constructor as the instance is not guaranteed to be fully constructed until the constructor has exited.  Be especially wary of uses that involve virtual functions (directly or indirectly). This can be a pretty quick route to dying due to a pure virtual method invocation.

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for `this`.

Comment: I thought he was looking for that.

Answer (score 2):

If You write an instance method like for example:

```
void MyClass::foo(some params);
```

the compiler adds a special parameter to the method by which an address of an instance is  passed. You can imagine that instead of a signature above, the compiler creates something like this:

```
//this is pseudocode
void MyClass::foo(MyClass * const this, some params);
```

This is one of the reasons, why for example You cant pass instance methods directly as callbacks.

In the body of any instance method, You can use a special keyword **this** as a const pointer to the instance.

Static methods don't get that pointer so You can't use **this** keyword in their definitions.

If You create a const method like like:

```
class MyClass
{
    void foo(some params);
    void foo(some params) const;
}
```

it is like there was a second method

```
//this is pseudocode
void MyClass::foo(const MyClass * const this, some params);
```

and the compiler can make an overload resolution based on the constness of the the object for which the method is called